# Oracle Apex Throw error when validation is false even once

Tags: oracle-apex

In Oracle Apex I have a validation on my grid on pressing the submit button.

The validation code is something like this:

```
IF EMP_SAL <10000
LOOP
Return error_msg ;
error_msg =:= EMP_NAME||'has salary less than 10000'
END LOOP;
END IF;
```

The validation type is inline field with notification so it highlights the error rows.

The problem is even if one row passes condition, it proceeds to submit.
I want it to stop even if one row fails the conditon with the inline error message.

So in case of validations looping through each selected row, even if it passes for oenr ow and rest all fail, it still proceeds for page processing.

Can it not be stopped even if there is one error?

Answer (score 0):

That is not the behaviour I'm seeing:

Create an editable IG on the EMP table. Add a validation on the SAL column of type "Expression" with source `:SAL > 2000` .

Run the page and do following actions:

- In one row, update salary to a value 5000
- In another row, update salary to a value 100
- click "Save".

The validation will fire and show the error message for the row with salary value 100.

- Click Actions > Data > Refresh to refresh the report with data stored in the database.
- Observe that the first row still has the original salary value and not 5000.